# FOR KEY SHARE - what are 'key values'?

Tags: postgresql

The documentation states

> A key-shared lock blocks other transactions from performing DELETE or any UPDATE that changes the key values.

Does "key values" refer to the primary key, or the unique keys, or the indexed keys, or the columns used for the SELECT query?

Answer (score 2):

The term *key values* refers foreign keys.

Alvaro Herrera, the author of the patch in Postgres 9.3 wrote (per [this source](https://github.com/michaelpq/michaelpq.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2013-01-29-postgres-9-3-feature-highlight-for-key-share-and-for-no-key-update.markdown)):

> Foreign key triggers now use FOR KEY SHARE instead of FOR SHARE; this
>   means the concurrency improvement applies to them, which is the whole
>   point of this patch.

You can also find this mention in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS):

> Currently, the set of columns considered for the UPDATE case are those that have a unique index on them that can be used in a foreign key (so partial indexes and expressional indexes are not considered), but this may change in the future.

Comment: The FOR KEY SHARE lock doesn't wait when row is locked with level weaker than FOR UPDATE. This is in documentation. What's little bit harder to find is the FOR UPDATE lock is always taken when table has triggers while for table without trigger, FOR NO KEY UPDATE lock can sometimes be chosen when update command actually doesn't update anything. I encountered this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57681970/653539 .

Comment: git commit message link: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=0ac5ad5134f2769ccbaefec73844f8504c4d6182