# what is the practical use of FOR KEY SHARE In postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am unable to understand where i will practically use it.
According to the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html) it says

> Behaves similarly to FOR SHARE, except that the lock is weaker: SELECT
>   FOR UPDATE is blocked, but not SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE. A key-shared
>   **lock blocks other transactions from performing DELETE or any UPDATE**
>   **that changes the key values**, but not other UPDATE, and neither does it
>   prevent SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE, SELECT FOR SHARE, or SELECT FOR KEY
>   SHARE.

But i tried and it is allowing all updates possible . i even tried changing the keys. May be I failed to understand what the docs refers to as **keys** (I thought it was foreign key [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073125/for-key-share-what-are-key-values?rq=1) and because it did not get blocked as said in docs i tried updating all and everything worked without getting blocked). I experimented this by having two psql terminals emulating two concurrent transactions.

**Transaction 1**

```
db1=> begin;
BEGIN
db1=> SELECT * from table_base FOR key share;
 base_id | foreign_id | nonkey1 
---------+------------+---------
 112 |          2 | plaexpl
  21 |          2 | harish
 111 |          2 | harish
(3 rows)

db1=> select * from table_foreign ;
foreign_id |  value  
------------+---------
      2 | val2
     12 | val1new
     44 | newval3
(3 rows)

db1=> \d table_base 
                  Table "public.table_base"
 Column   |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
 ------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 base_id    | integer               |           |          | 
 foreign_id | integer               |           |          | 
 nonkey1    | character varying(50) |           |          | 
 Foreign-key constraints:
  "table_base_foreign_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (foreign_id) REFERENCES 
 table_foreign(foreign_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Transaction 2

```
db1=> begin;
BEGIN
db1=> UPDATE table_base set base_id = 221 where base_id=21;
UPDATE 1
db1=> UPDATE table_base set foreign_id = 12 where nonkey1='harish';
UPDATE 2
db1=> UPDATE table_base set nonkey1='newharish' where nonkey1='harish';
UPDATE 2
db1=> end;
COMMIT
db1=> SELECT * from table_base;
 base_id | foreign_id |  nonkey1  
---------+------------+-----------
     112 |          2 | plaexpl
     111 |         12 | newharish
     221 |         12 | newharish
(3 rows)

db1=> begin;
BEGIN
db1=> UPDATE table_foreign set foreign_id = 33 where value = 'val1new';
UPDATE 1
db1=> UPDATE table_foreign set value ='newvalfor33' where foreign_id = 33;
UPDATE 1
db1=> end;
COMMIT
db1=> SELECT * from table_foreign ;
 foreign_id |    value    
------------+-------------
          2 | val2
         44 | newval3
         33 | newvalfor33
(3 rows)
```

[image]

More info about the tables in above example
[image]
If it is allowing all updates, then what is the difference between 'FOR KEY SHARE' and normal 'SELECT' (except that it blocks SELECT FOR UPDATE).
what is the practical use of this ?

Comment: Can we see `\d table_base`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe added the screen shot in the question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i added the screenshot to show the output tables the psql emitted

Comment: ok sure .... i will do that now

Comment: I am having 12.1 .. i added 9.3 tag as it was apparently the version in which these locks were introduced. may be i can remove that tag if it is confusing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i added the code now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`FOR KEY SHARE` is mostly useful when tables with a foreign key constraint are modified: The referenced row (on the remote table) will (automatically) receive such a lock so that no referenced key can be modified concurrently.

You see no effect because your table does not contain a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: I changed the base_id to be PRIMARY KEY and still i can change the foreign_id

Comment: Yes, but not the primary key column.

Comment: but it did block the PRIMARY KEY UPDATE .

Comment: so that means PRIMARY KEY of the table being locked cannot be modified. if i did not have a foreign relationship with another table will this still hold good ?

Comment: yes, i checked and it still holds good.. then why did they say that FOREIGN KEY cannot be changed. is it not the PRIMARY KEY ?

Comment: "They" don't say that. You get a `KEY SHARE` lock **on the remote table** if you insert or delete a row in the table with the foreign key constraint. That lock will prevent modifications on keys **in the remote table**.

Comment: you already write a blog post: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/